# What if the earth stopped rotating and revolving at the same time?

Tags: earth, astrophysics

What will happen to us are we going to move in a tangential direction with earth axis of rotation ?

Comment: I'd say this is off topic. Try this instead: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10581/effects-of-a-non-rotating-earth/10582#10582

Comment: Rotationally, we don't have orbital velocity, even at the equator. However our speed in orbit about the sun, about 15 km/sec, is greater than escape velocity, 11.2 km/sec, so half of us would be squished, while the other half would fly into the vacuum of space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hypothetical scenario with no basis in fact.

Comment: Watch the movie the day the earth stood still.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a physics question/off topic question.  Due to the [law of conservation of momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation) things that are in motion stay in motion.  If the earth was magically seized upon by some cosmic tractor beam, it would basically be squished flat (imagine dropping an egg on the floor, where the floor represents the opposing force of the tractor beam).  If it was a gradual controlled reduction of speed (like an elevator's motion), I guess nothing would happen.  But that doesn't really make any sense either, because that doesn't explain how you got rid of the gravitational effects of the sun and everything else.